# What is the literary device when a character takes part in a real play in the story?

Tags: symbols, literary-device, reference, allusion

In the story, one of the characters acts in a play. This play also exists in real life, and it has a symbolic meaning to the story. Would this be an example of intertextuality or would it be a different literary device?

Comment: The play is an actual play which exists in real life, created by another author. For example, one of the characters in the story decides to audition for a role in a rendition of Hamlet in the story.

Comment: So in the play a character has a part on *Breaking Bad* or works at Amazon or meets a friend at Starbucks for coffee. Not, unlike Hamlet, a play within a play.

Comment: ...or perhaps a dream within in a dream? Could you please provide more detail? i.e "symbolic meaning? Right now it just sounds like another meta story.

Comment: In the story, the character's mother decides to act in a play called the little foxes, and the character which she plays represents greed and reliance on others. Would the literary device used here be intertextuality or something else?

Comment: Symbolism, analogy?

Comment: "A play within a play".  This is sometimes called an [embedded narrative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_within_a_story).

Comment: As to whether it's intertextuality, it might be but isn't necessarily. Intertextuality implies a relationship between texts (things which are constructed by human beings), showing how the outer work is fabricated or fictitious or constructed. In A Midsummer Night's Dream, the players' play subverts (or deconstructs) the nature of the romantic relationships in the main play, showing how the latter are a confection not to be taken seriously. But if Hamlet sees a play about revenge and decides revenge is good, that isn't pointing out the fictitious nature of his life.

Comment: Questions about intertextuality and literary devices are better asked on Literature Stack Exchange. https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a specialist topic and is therefore off-topic here; questions about literary devices are better asked on literature.stackexchange.com